# Text centered at top of circle path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get my text "HubsSpokes" to center at the top of a circular path.

```
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\huge|HubsSpokes}}}] ($(current page text area.west)+(0,.25in)$,0) circle (1.4cm);
```

However, my text is not appearing at the top of the circle, it is appearing on the left side of the circle and extending off the page. Ideally, I'd like it to be centered on my page. I am not wanting the circle itself to be drawn. Should I be using an arc instead?

What can I do to position my text at the top of the circular path?

Comment: why not try `current page.west`

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this. It's made with `arc` command because this way you can control path starting and ending points and it's center. With a `circle` the path's center could be any position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.text}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\huge|HubsSpokes}}}] ($(current page text area.west)+(0,.25in)$,0) arc(180:0:1.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! But, how would I center this on the page (i.e. between text area.west and text area.east)? I have tried setting `current page text area.center` but that sets the starting point of the arc, not the middle point of the arc.

Comment: @kojow7 In my example `($(current page text area.west)+(0,.25in)$,0)` places the pencil and from this point the arc is drawn. `arc(180:0:1.4cm)` means that on this point will start an arc with 1.4cm radius with angle 180 to 0. Therefore the center is 1.4cm to the right of  `($(current page text area.west)+(0,.25in)$,0)`. In your case start from `current page text area.center+(-radius,0)`. As an alternative to `calc` you could say `([xshift=-radius]current page text area.center)` where `radius` is your desired value.